# How do i make an app running on iphone 5 fit the screen of iphone 4 and 3

Tags: iphone, resize, autosize

I have a an app running on Iphone 5 and all the elements fit perfectly, I want to run the app also on Iphone 3 and Iphone 4.

I read a few articles about the Auto Sizing but I could not find any information specific for this issue.

Do I need to have a multiple Images with different sizes?
Do I need to set the elements size grammatically ?

Any help guys....

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to have a multiple Images with different sizes.
- You need to set the elements size programmatic ally in viewWillApear method.

> ```
> -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
> {
>     if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
>     {
>         [splashImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 548)];
>         [splashImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_Image_320X568@2x.jpg"]];
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         [splashImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
>         [splashImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash_Image_320X.jpg"]];
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If your application is thought for iPhone 5, it will be complicated due to the smaller screen size, but here is what you have to do :

- All your images are supposed to be in two sizes, classic and @2x. The classic size will be used for iPhone 3GS.
- If you are already using autolayout you're ready, cross your finger and let's go.
- If not, you should think about using autolayout, read some tutorial about it, but simply it allows you to design a single interface for all your screen sizes.
- If you don't want to use autolayout (or if you can't), you should place all your elements directly in your code to be sure they aren't "out" the screen.

Comment: If not using AutoLayout you can get a longer way the Autoresize mask and just make sure that the root view of you viewController is set to grow in the width and height.