# how can i write the code for iphone 3.5 inches screen and 4 inches screen

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am developing an app. In the app I wrote the code for a 3.5-inch screen. I took one view controller; in this view controller I want to display two images, one for the top (Imagelogo) and another for the bottom (Image Building). On the 3.5-inch screen there is no problem with the display. But on the 4-inch screen, there is a display problem. The two images are not displayed properly. I don't know how to write the same code for both the 3.5 and 4-inch screen. Can I use macros? Please give me ideas, anyone. I am new to programming. Thanks in advance.

The below is my code.

Viewcontroller.m (3.5 inches screen)

This image will be displayed on top.

```
imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 10, 162, 57)];
imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo-01.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imgLogo];
```

This image will be displayed on bottom

```
imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 320,140 )];
imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-02.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];
```

Comment: plz use autosizing property.

Comment: you can use auto layout .

Comment: you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122401/how-do-i-make-an-app-running-on-iphone-5-fit-the-screen-of-iphone-4-and-3

Comment: use autolayout to adjust images according to screen sizes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

You can autoResize feature in the in the interface builder or use it via code.

You can use Apple's Auto Layout system if your app support IOS 5 and above.

You can place the images according the screen size via code

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
       //iphone 5 image 
}else
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your "Viewcontroller.h" define float scaleY;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
   float scaleY;
}
@end
```

In your "Viewcontroller.m" class

in your viewDidLoad method after [super viewDidLoad]; put your scaleY value for your different screen size devices in iPhone family.

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector: @selector(scale)])
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        result = CGSizeMake(result.width * scale, result.height * scale);
        NSLog(@"Height ........%f",result.height);

        if(result.height == 480 || result.height == 960)
        {
            // iPhone 3.5 inches Screen
            scaleY=1.0;

        }
        else if(result.height == 1136)
        {
            // iPhone 4 inches Screen
            scaleY=1.18333f;

        }
    }
}
```

Then multiply the scaleY value with your "y" position of the views.

```
UIImageView *imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 10*scaleY, 162, 57)];
imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo-01.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imgLogo];

UIImageView *imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320*scaleY, 320, 140 )];
imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-02.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];
```

You can use this "scaleY" value (as shown above) throughout your code to multiply it with your y position of the corresponding views. Since iPhone Family Devices are different in heights so we can only change their "y" position.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Though I also use this method, it will result in views and images getting a bit enlarged vertically. Icons do not remain perfect square in 4" screen.

Answer (score 0):

just try with autoresizingmask like this.

```
 UIImageView *imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 10, 162, 57)];


    imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo-01.png"];
    [imgLogo setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin)];

    [self.view addSubview:imgLogo];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick fix to your issue but i would suggest to use Auto layout.

```
 if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
    {    
         imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 10, 162, 57)];
       imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo-01.png"];
       [self.view addSubview:imgLogo]; 
       imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 420,140 )];
       imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-02.png"];
       [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];            
    }
    else
    {
       imgLogo=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 10, 162, 57)];
       imgLogo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo-01.png"];
       [self.view addSubview:imgLogo]; 
       imgBuilding=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 320,140 )];
       imgBuilding.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-02.png"];
       [self.view addSubview:imgBuilding];     
    }
```

Hope this will help you out.